# Django login with facebook Error: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am tired of this issue, please somebody can explain me where am I wrong?

1. I installed `django-social-auth` and add settings.py to installed apps :

   'social_auth'
2. I added these lines to settings.py:

   ```
   AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (  'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
                       'social_auth.backends.contrib.github.GithubBackend',
                           'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)

   SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_complete'
   SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete'

   SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_complete'
   SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete'
   SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False
   SOCIAL_AUTH_FORCE_POST_DISCONNECT = True
   SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True

   SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'

   FACEBOOK_APP_ID = '11036686*****'
   FACEBOOK_API_SECRET = '6290e378b078cc0cad*******'
   SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('facebook', 'github')
   ```

context_processors :

```
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends',
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_backends',
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_login_redirect',
```

Then I go to facebook developers page and add:

appdomains:

```
localhost
```

Site URL

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

And 
I click `Embedded browser OAuth Login` and enabled.

And I am getting  this error:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

What am I missing? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your server as `./manage.py runserver localhost:8000`

and in your browser  go to `localhost:8000` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`